# Are there any limitations to row Iterator in Apache POI?

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

```
 try {File inputFile = new File(str2);
        File inputFile1 = new File (str1);
         XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(new FileInputStream(inputFile));
         XSSFWorkbook wb1 =new XSSFWorkbook(new FileInputStream(inputFile1));

          XSSFSheet sheet1 = wb.getSheetAt(0);
          XSSFSheet sheet2;
     Iterator<Row> iterator1 =sheet1.iterator();
 while (iterator1.hasNext()){
            row1=iterator1.next();

           cell1= row1.getCell(4);
           String output=cell1.toString();

           System.out.println(cell1.toString());
          //a1.add(cell1.toString());
           // int m = jList1.getSelectedIndex();
         }
        catch (Exception e){

              Logger.getLogger(def.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, e);
            }

            }
```

It doesn't read print after 10k rows although there are 13k rows. Any solutions? Can SXSSF Sheet can be used?

Comment: The number of rows should be only limited by the format. For Excel 2003 it is already 65536. Can you show how you are accessing the file?

Comment: this is how I am reading the file

Comment: I can iterate over mote than 10.000 rows exactly like you did. No idea where your problem is then.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, generally there is no limit to iterator's size(assuming there is enough RAM or it is buffering from a file). in your case I suggest two things:

1. make sure the Apache POI doesn't have a default limit.
2. There is no weird character on the 10k'th that iterator may consider it as the end of the buffer

Comment: When I do this  int  n = sheet1.getLastRowNum();System.out.println(n); I get 10000. Perhaps there is a limitation. :-(

Comment: Yep, just checked it, the excel limitation is 10000. see this link ----->    http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/excel-help/excel-specifications-and-limits-HA103980614.aspx    . just create a copy of that file, read the first 10k line and delete them, read the next 10k line and delete them and continue until the file is empty. This is a stupid limitation of excel so good luck

Comment: @nafas Quoted from your link: _1,048,576 rows_

Comment: look for "Items displayed in filter drop-down lists". that is what your iterator would see.

Comment: @nafas Please elaborate why you think the limit Excel has for drop-down lists applies to iterating over rows? I can iterate over more than 10.000 rows with an iterator like that exactly like the OP did.

Comment: imagine you request a buffer from a excel file, the object would only receive whatever is in the filtered list. This is what excel would return due to an initial call.If it was an excel gui interface we could scroll down and this filter would refresh automatically. now my solution was to read the top 10k  rows and delete them, then create a new buffer to read the top 10k rows(if pervious 10k rows were deleted then we get the next 10k).

Comment: @nafas Why can I read over 10.000 rows with an iterator just like OP did then? Without removing previous rows or anything obviously. Do you any source on that or are you just making assumptions?

Comment: it was based on a deductive reasoning. There could be a possibility of 32 vs 64 bits architecture. either way there is a high chance that my solution work.